# can you please tell me Augmented reality markerless Sdks for unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

how can we make markerless augmented reality in unity 3d using vuforia sdk

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot. There are other solutions like Kudan or Metaio that support markerless. I think Vuforia once had a markerless demo, but it looks like they given up on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Metaio was the leading one which was acquired by APPLE Inc. for Markerless Augmented Reality. Kudan and Wikitude are other alternatives.

You can find a list of Augemented Reality SDK's comparison in the below mentioned link's.
http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks
https://creator.zoho.com/reitmayr/augmented-reality-sdks/view-embed/AR_SDKs